# Why is curly brace indentation messed up in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the Visual Studio 2015 Release Candidate.

In previous versions of Visual Studio I've always programmed with both `Automatic brace completion` and `Automatically format completed block on }` disabled.

In previous versions when creating a block, the curly braces were automatically formatted when typing `enter` `{` `enter` `}`

Which would result in:

```
class Foo
{
}
```

In VS 2015 that results in:

```
class Foo
{
    }
```

Is there a new setting I'm missing or is this a bug in the RC?

Comment: The would be a config for that somewhere.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520764/did-c-sharp-formatting-change-in-visual-studio-2015-and-how-can-i-change-it-bac

Comment: @EvanCarslake Any idea where?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I came across that question before posting my own.  The answers there didn't solve my problem.

Comment: it in options, editor for relevant language. but i think it's a bad idea to have to opt out of all kinds of things in order to get the few features that one finds useful. rather i would had a nice list of e.g. formatting that i could opt in to *if i wanted*. as all old-timers agree, developer studio 6.0 was the bestest. since then, only downhill.

Comment: @Alf that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Do you know the specific option to fix this problem?  I've already looked through the options *twice* and fiddled around with a lot of them.

Comment: not sure but i would try the "automatically format braces", (http://i.imgur.com/8KpHsEa.png)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah, I should have mentioned this is for C#.  The `Formatting -> General` section for C# doesn't have an equivalent option. :/

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I concur, and why I really despise Eclipse. "I am typing, dont think you help me dammit! You wasting my time!"

Comment: Just to make sure - is your code compilable? I've seen the formatter do weird things for certain kinds of incomplete / syntactically broken code even in older VS.

Comment: @Luaan: That's what I initially thought the problem was but that's not it.  The code is correct and compilable (tested in a new project).

Answer (score 5):

Okay, I tested it out. The result seems rather obvious - you told Visual Studio *not* to format your code on `}`, so it doesn't do that.

In other words, the behaviour in the *older* Visual Studios seem to be broken - even though you've specified you don't want VS to do the formatting for you, it does. After all, as you're typing, your cursor ends up on `_` here:

```
class Test
{
    _
```

Then you just add a `}`, so it's

```
class Test
{
    }
```

Which older Visual Studio automatically formats as

```
class Test
{
}
```

even if you have unchecked `Automatically format completed block on }`. This is obviously auto-formatting - if you press `Ctrl+Z`, it will revert the formatting, not the `}` itself. Arguably, the behaviour in VS2015 is a *fix* of a bug present in the old versions.

This becomes much more apparent when I start using crazy formatting with your settings. Code like this:

```
class Test
{
    public
        string
            Ana
    {
        get; set;
        }
    }
```

Becomes

```
class Test
{
    public
        string
            Ana
    {
        get; set;
        }
        }
```

on VS2013! This is obviously wrong. On the other hand, VS2015 correctly applies *no formatting* - it simply positions your caret at the place it *thinks* you want it, and doesn't apply any formatting automatically, ever.

So, is there a way to get to the old behaviour? Nothing simple, I'm affraid - my guess is that MS simply considers to be the proper behaviour, and the old one being buggy, and it's hard to argue with that. There's some workarounds you could do to get closer to the old behaviour, like manually disabling all the auto formatting *except* for the brace alignment, but it will still change the behaviour a bit.

Still, I can see how the behaviour you expect would be desirable. If you think it's worth it, you could try filing it as a bug on Connect, though I wouldn't give it much of a chance of being "fixed" - IMO it's a fix to a bug, not a bug.

Comment: Hmm, I get what you're saying but I'm not buying it.  I'm having trouble understanding how unindenting closing braces can be considered auto-formatting but all of the other basic indentation you get while typing is not considered auto-formatting.  I've always understood `Automatically format completed block on }` as meaning "Apply all of the **actual** auto-formatting rules you have set when ending the block of code you're typing". Furthermore, this bug (if it *is* a bug) has been in Visual Studio since at least 2008.  Why fix it now?

Comment: @inlinevoid Well, the distinction I've mentioned holds - auto formatting actually changes the output. The other indentation is just moving your cursor. And of course, you don't fix bugs noöne cares about - that's wasting resources. However, when you rewrite the whole code anyway (I'd guess this has to do with the Roslyn integration and such), you tend to avoid even those bugs noöne cared about. I understand why it's annoying, of course, but it does make more sense (even though I'd still consider it silly). Perhaps you could just code a simple add-in to handle this?