# Formatting issue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, autoformatting

There seem to be a few changes (bugs?) in the auto-formatting feature of VS2015.

## 1: It has already been reported with the RC but was not fixed for the release:

If I type:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

it is formatted to:

```
public string Name
{ get; set; }
```

I have "Leave block on single line" set.

## 2: if I type, e.g.

```
if (array.Count() > 1)
    DoOne(array);
else
    if (array.Count() == 1)
        DoMany(array);
```

it is corrected to:

```
if (array.Count() > 1)
    DoOne(array);
else
    if (array.Count() == 1)
    DoMany(array);
```

Comment: I asked a similar question here: [Did C# formatting change in Visual Studio 2015? And how can I change it back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520764/did-c-sharp-formatting-change-in-visual-studio-2015-and-how-can-i-change-it-bac)

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the post that I had in mind in #1 and I voted for it. Did you get any satisfying answers so far?

Comment: I added the issues also here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1711675