# Formatting properties on one line in VS2015 Community edition

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-formatting, word-wrap

How can you outline properties in VS2015 Community edition? The default setting is this:

```
public int Foo
{ get; set; }
```

but I will outline like this:

```
public int Foo { get; set; }
```

I have look by the settings of vs, but if I uncheck 'Leave block on single line' *(see image below)*, is the result this:

```
public int Foo
{ 
    get; set; 
}
```

[image: settings]

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30520764/did-c-sharp-formatting-change-in-visual-studio-2015-and-how-can-i-change-it-bac).

> Go to Tools > Options > Text editor > C# > Formatting > Wrapping
>
> Check "Leave block on single line" and "Leave statements and member declarations 
>     on the same line"